# TypeError while adding elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to take inputs from the command line and convert them to commands and then execute those commands, however i'm getting a typeError with generator.
Can someone please tell me as to why this is caused and also what is this generator object?

> cmd1=''.join('s1.'+info+'('+s2+')')
>
> TypeError: Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly

```
n=int(input())
    s1=set(int(x) for x in input().split())
    loop_length=int(input())
    for _ in range(loop_length):
        info,r=input().split()
        s2=(int(x) for x in input().split())
        cmd1='s1.'+str(info)+'('+s2+')'
        eval(cmd1)
    print(s1)
```

Comment: I would suspect that its your `set` that it's objecting to, but it's hard to tell with undescriptive variable names and no whitespace exactly what's going on here. Actually your code is different from what you highlighted? Are you trying to use `.join` on a string?

Comment: A generator expression is assigned to `s2`. Convert it to a tuple (or list) first.

Comment: The error seemed to be because of the set element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a generator object which will return ints. This generator of ints needs to be converted to a str.

There are multiple ways to do this, I'm unsure exactly what you need. In order to convert each int that the generator would return into a str, I would use map.

```
str_s2 = map(str, s2)
```

However, this returns another generator.

To convert a generator into a str, you need to have some sort of idea on the output you want. If you want the output to be a comma separated list of your numbers, use join.

```
str_s2 = ', '.join(map(str, s2))
```

Comment: The error seemed to be because i was using s2 as a string in the code, fixed it, thank you !